# How to sort multiple $addToSet arrays in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoDB aggregate query to get some data and then I am using `$addToSet` to get arrays of unique values. I want that array to be sorted so I tried doing `$unwind -> $sort -> $push` but the problem is it only works for one array I want to do the same for all the arrays that I have in my result. Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Comment: one common way to do it, is `$unwind` `$sort` and then `$group` back to restore the document structure, if you search how to sort array you will find many answeres i guess, if you still have problems, send sample data if you can(data in and expected data out) , so someone can help

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried the method you have mentioned unfortunately for multiple arrays we don't have a straight forward method so we have to repeat the process multiple time

Comment: send sample data if you can, and the method you tried, its possible that those arrays can be separated, and more simple solution to exist